# Python3.7 Missing pip package

Tags: python, docker-compose, pip

I keep getting this error that this package is missing. I used a conda enviroment on my local PC but I am trying to compile a docker-compose on server. Is there anything I can do?

I have try using different version of item but I get the same problem over again.

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
Copy . ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["./app/server.py"]
```

requirments.txt

```
aniso8601==8.0.0
asn1crypto==1.3.0
attrs==19.3.0
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.10.34
botocore==1.13.34
bz2file==0.98
cachetools==3.1.1
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cryptography==2.8
docutils==0.15.2
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
flask-restplus==0.13.0
gensim==3.8.1
google-api-core==1.14.3
google-auth==1.7.2
google-cloud-bigquery==1.22.0
google-cloud-core==1.1.0
google-cloud-storage==1.23.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==1.4.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
jmespath==0.9.4
jsonschema==3.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mecab-python3==0.996.2
mkl-fft==1.0.15
mkl-random==1.1.0
mkl-service==2.3.0
more-itertools==8.1.0
nltk==3.4.5
numexpr==2.7.0
numpy==1.17.4
pandas==0.25.3
protobuf==3.11.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.7
pycparser==2.19
PyMySQL==0.9.3
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pyrsistent==0.15.7
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-fft==1.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 34)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-fft==1.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 34))
ERROR: Service 'server' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am using a ubuntu 18.04 lts VM on google cloud platform.

I can add more details if need. I am kind of stump how to fix this issue

Comment: It seems like you have the wrong version of mkl-fft installed. Did you try pip install mkl-fft==1.0.9?

Comment: you mean separately in a docker file? Also it work on conda env I use on local pc . Yes, have tried 1.0.9 but no luck either

Comment: You can’t use Conda with Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of `mkl-fft` is [1.0.6](https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/1.0.6/). Fix your `requirements.txt`:

```
mkl-fft==1.0.6
```

*Upd*. Intel [provide](https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/1.0.6/#files) wheels for Python up to 3.6, but not 3.7 or 3.8, and no source distribution. Either downgrade your Python to 3.6 or install from the source code: `pip install 'git+https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft.git#egg=mkl_fft'`. In the `requirements.txt`:

```
git+https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft.git#egg=mkl_fft
```

But you need to install MKL library.

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-fft==1.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 34)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-fft==1.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 34))